# How to open a particular app's setting from WinUI/UWP application

Tags: uwp, winui-3

It is possible to open the Settings App [programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app?msclkid=41ff660dc56011ecb886f32a44907e2c#apps), there are lot of options but it does not provide details about how to open a setting for a particular app.

I have also seen that we can open a particular app's settings  from start menu. This may mean we can also programmatically open a particular app's settings page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

** UPDATE **

Setting option as in start menu
[image]

App's setting page, as provided by the OS
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there are lot of options but it does not provide details about how to open a setting for a particular app.

You need register launch uri for particular app, and you can get parameter in target app's onactive method. For example `testapp:setting`, you could get `setting` string from parameter.

Then call navigate method to setting page base base on the received parameter. For more info please refer to [Handle URI activation](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation).

And the other way is build [jump list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.startscreen.jumplistitem?view=winrt-22000) for the app. The jump list is a system-provided menu that appears when the user right-clicks a program in the taskbar or on the Start menu.

```
var jumpList = await Windows.UI.StartScreen.JumpList.LoadCurrentAsync();

// Disable the system-managed jump list group.
jumpList.SystemGroupKind = Windows.UI.StartScreen.JumpListSystemGroupKind.None;

var taskItem = JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments(
              "/Setting", "Setting");

// Set the description. (Optional.)
taskItem.Description = "Compose a new message to " + "Nico";

// Set the logo for this jump list item. Must be ms-appx: or ms-appdata:.
taskItem.Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png");


// Remove any previously added custom jump list items.
jumpList.Items.Add(taskItem);

// Save the changes to the app's jump list.
await jumpList.SaveAsync();
```

And you could process launch parameter.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.Launch && e.Arguments == "/Setting")
    {
        // navigate to setting page.
    }
}
```

**Update**

You could use `ms-settings:appsfeatures-app` to open current app's setting page with launcher in code behind. But it could not use to open other app's setting content.

Comment: Apologies, I meant the settings for the app provided by the OS, please see the screen shot added to the question

Comment: You could use `ms-settings:appsfeatures-app` to open current app's setting page in the current app. But it could not use to open other app's setting content.

Comment: give me a day, I would try it

Comment: It works,   `await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:appsfeatures-app"));`